# Want to read text content from web browser control in wp7 or wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application in which a am using TTS(text to speech) conversion and in the same way i want to read web browser content for converting these text content to speech.

Comment: What did you try ? What errors or problems you faced ?

Comment: i searched alot but not found way how to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.yourURL.com"));
httpReq.BeginGetResponse(HTTPWebRequestCallBack, httpReq);
private void HTTPWebRequestCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
        string strResponse = "";
        try
        {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
        try
        {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        WebResponse response = httpRequest.EndGetResponse(result);

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //do you logic of TTS here 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {}
        });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
        }
```

This will get all text inside the page including of course HTML tags
if you want more professional way to get specific tags in your web page
check the following post 
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTML_Page_parsing_using_HTMLAgilityPack